# Can I get the on-demand EC2 instances if spot instances are not available in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a requirement to create a set of c5.12xlarge EC2 Linux instances for my  CI/CT. I am creating these instances using terraform and using aws spot instances.
Since couple of days I am seeing my terraform apply fails with "There is no Spot capacity available that matches your request" error due to unavailability of instances in AWS.

How do I get rid of this and get the instances created? Is there any way in terraform I can create an on-demand EC2 instances in case spot EC2 instances are not available.

Comment: I don't know terraform, but you might look at [EC2 Fleets](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-fleet-manage-thousands-of-on-demand-and-spot-instances-with-one-request/) -- they appear to allow you to spin up the lowest cost (including a combination of spot and on-demand) instances based on available resources.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit for spot instance, and I am not sure did the terraform cancel subscription after creation? because there is warning note.

> NOTE: Because their behavior depends on the live status of the spot
>   market, Spot Instance Requests have a unique lifecycle that makes them
>   behave differently than other Terraform resources. Most importantly:
>   there is no guarantee that a Spot Instance exists to fulfill the
>   request at any given point in time. See the AWS Spot Instance
>   documentation for more information.

[spot_instance_request](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/spot_instance_request.html)

**Spot Request Limits**

> By default, there is an account limit of `20 Spot Instances` per Region.
>   If you terminate your Spot Instance **but do not cancel the request, the
>   request counts against this limit until Amazon EC2 detects the
>   termination and closes the request.**
>
> Spot Instance limits are dynamic. When your account is new, your limit
>   might be lower than 20 to start, but can increase over time. In
>   addition, your account might have limits on specific Spot Instance
>   types. If you submit a Spot Instance request and you receive the error
>   Max spot instance count exceeded, you can complete the AWS Support
>   Center Create case form to request a Spot Instance limit increase. For
>   Limit type, choose EC2 Spot Instances. For more information, see
>   Amazon EC2 Service Limits.

[using-spot-limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-limits.html)

you can create an instance on_demand

```
# Create a new instance of the latest Ubuntu 14.04 on an
# t2.micro node with an AWS Tag naming it "HelloWorld"
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

[instance aws terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html)